# Bad path in GIMP 2.10.22 from Macports causing plug-in-file-gif.ui, script-fu.init, to be unfindable during execution

Tags: xcode, macports, gimp

This is my first time posting, so please forgive my bad formatting and bring forth suggestions for improvement.

Main Problem:

Trying to do a File -> Export As with a .gif extension is causing a failure to find plug-in-file-gif.ui.

```
Error loading UI file '/opt/local/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-gif-save/share/gimp/2.0/ui/plug-ins/plug-in-file-gif.ui':
```

I found the file elsewhere:

```
$ sudo find / -name "plug-in-file-gif.ui"

/opt/local/share/gimp/2.0/ui/plug-ins/plug-in-file-gif.ui
```

There's clearly some kind of path concatenation problem happening that's making GIMP unable to find its plugins.

I've installed The GIMP 2.10.22 using Macports, including the GAP library. My install was:

```
$ sudo port install gimp-app gimp-gap
```

I've done several un-installs and cleans to make sure I'm not getting leftovers from previous builds. I'm not seeing any significant errors during install.

I've also tried deleting the

```
"/Users/thebitmaster/Library/Application Support/GIMP/2.10/"
```

directory in between.

The question here is whether this is a local config issue (much more likely) or an issue with the Macport disti that needs to be reported back to their admins.

---------------------- More Details --------------

Running

```
$ port diagnose
```

Gives me:

```
Error: currently installed version of Xcode, none, is not supported by MacPorts.  For your currently installed system, only the following versions of Xcode are supported:  11.3.1 11.3 11.2.1 11.2 11.1 11.0 10.3 10.2.1 10.2 10.1 10.0
Warning: you have leftover files from an older version of Xcode. You should delete them by using, /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder
```

I'm getting very mixed messages about my Xcode install:

I check for xcode (some version of which is obviously installed or I couldn't compile at all)

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

...and I get...

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

If I then run:

```
$ xcode-select -v
```

I get:

```
xcode-select version 2354.
```

But if I do:

```
$ system_profiler SPDeveloperToolsDataType
```

I get nothing.

If I look in the App Store for Xcode, I get the Cloud Download icon, meaning, presumably, it doesn't think it's installed.

There were several other complaints from "port diagnose" but those have been addressed.

I tried copying the "plug-in-file-gif.ui" into my user directory at:

```
"/Users/thebitmaster/Library/Application Support/GIMP/2.10/plug-ins"
```

...but I still get the same error.

At the moment I'm inside  /opt/local/etc/gimp/2.0/gimprc trying to override the paths.

I found this:

```
# The variable ${gimp_dir} is set to the value of the environment variable
# GIMP2_DIRECTORY or, if that is not set, the compiled-in default value is
# used.  If GIMP2_DIRECTORY is not an absolute path, it is interpreted
# relative to your home directory.
```

My bash environment does *not* have GIMP2_DIRECTORY defined, which seems to imply that it's using the compiled default, which might be where the problem is coming from. I haven't tried to back-trace the source of the compiled default value yet as I haven't spelunked makefiles in a long time.

I'm experimenting with GIMP2_DIRECTORY and the plug-in paths in gimprc to see if I can find a combination that works. So far doing so has caused more problems than it's solved. Without it, the GIMP runs mostly ok. I was able to do some frame animation with the Video->Move Path interface, so GAPS is at least partially functional. However, if I try to do Video-> MasterVideoencoder I get:

```
Plug-in crashed: "gap_vid_common_encoder"
(/opt/local/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/gap_vid_common_encoder)

The dying plug-in may have messed up GIMP's internal state. You may want to save your images and restart GIMP to be on the safe side.
```

On startup I'm also getting a:

```
    Unable to read initialization file script-fu.init
```

...error that I'm guessing is being caused by the same path problem.

System:

Macbook Pro 2013 running Mojave 10.14.6
GIMP 2.10.22
Macports 2.6.3

Comment: UPDATE: I've finally updated to Catalina and the new Xcode and will try a re-install of everything once that's done..

Comment: I've re-done the install after upgrading to Catalina and Xcode 11.6. I then did a full un-and-re-install of Macports, re-installed the GIMP, and am still seeing the same .gif export error.